# Is there any NLP library or package which can help in adding comma, punctuation, newlines appropriately to text?

Tags: nlp, preprocessing

I have a movie transcript without commas, punctuation, or newlines. Is there any NLP technique that can help to implement this?

Comment: But does it at least have capitalization?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this transformer model called [Re-Punctuate](https://huggingface.co/SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate).

Code:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, TFT5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')
model = TFT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')

input_text = 'the story of this brave brilliant athlete whose very being was questioned so publicly is one that still captures the imagination'
inputs = tokenizer.encode("punctuate: " + input_text, return_tensors="tf") 
result = model.generate(inputs)

decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(result[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(decoded_output)
```

Example:

> Input: the story of this brave brilliant athlete whose very being was
> questioned so publicly is one that still captures the imagination 
> Output: The story of this brave, brilliant athlete, whose very being
> was questioned so publicly, is one that still captures the
> imagination.

Installation: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with "text segmentation". NLP libraries have code for breaking given text into :

- Sentences
- Phrases
- Words

With this, you can break text into sentences and insert . or ? for each sentence. Similarly, dependency tree will help with inserting some punctuation marks (not all).

Example (breaking text into sentences):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "I was expecting a surplus of cute close-ups but Burton does surprisingly little to win us over He's never been big on treacle but a bit more warmth in this chilly movie which barely follows the outline of the 1941 original would have gone a long way"
text_sentences = nlp(text)
for sentence in text_sentences.sents:
    print(sentence.text)
```

Output is :

> I was expecting a surplus of cute close-ups but Burton does
>   surprisingly little to win us over

and

> He's never been big on treacle but a bit more warmth in this chilly
>   movie which barely follows the outline of the 1941 original would have
>   gone a long way

More details : https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to work only because you have "He" with a capital letter already. I tried this on all-lowercase and didn't quite get this as output.