# Adding punctuation for a long text

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, transformer

I want to add punctuation to a long text (youtube transcript) before using a Transformer pipeline for summarization.

I have found this answer here:
[original answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48575/is-there-any-nlp-library-or-package-which-can-help-in-adding-comma-punctuation?newreg=4c83717f50ec4a78943dd3eeae9511a1)

thus I have tried:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, TFT5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')
model = TFT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate')

input_text = 'the story of this brave brilliant athlete whose very being was questioned so publicly is one that still captures the imagination'
inputs = tokenizer.encode("punctuate: " + input_text, return_tensors="tf") 
result = model.generate(inputs)

decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(result[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(decoded_output)
```

While this is working fine with short sentences the token limit is 512 and I have text with lengths up to 13000 tokens.
This is not a problem for summarization I use longformer model that has limits of 16000, but I would like to know the best strategy to add punctuation for a long text.
How do you suggest splitting the text? other kinds of strategies? do you have a snippet of code?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have the same problem. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I used the longformer, but take in account that now the latest language models have a context length up to 4-8K character (some even much more) so you can maybe use LLaMA or another depending your needs. I would not use more than 2-3 k tokens for prompt because, some studies show that even if the model has a large context length is not exploiting the additional information

Comment: There are lots of longformer and LLaMA models on HuggingFace. Which ones did you find to be most suitable for YouTube transcripts? Which are the fastest?